# How to load fonts from GCS

Tags: python, fonts, path, python-imaging-library, google-cloud-storage

I want to load "fonts" from Google Storage, I've try two ways, but none of them work. Any pointers? Appreciated for any advices provided.

**First:**

> I follow the instruction `load_font_from_gcs(uri)`given in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266788/loading-fonts-into-imagefont-from-gcs), but I received an **NameError: name 'load_font_from_gcs' is not defined** message. I installed google storage dependency and execute `from google.cloud import storage`

.

**Second:**

> I try to execute the following code (reference #1) , and running into an `blob has no attribute open()` error, just the same answer I get it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71644994/blob-has-not-attribute-open), but as the reference in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_open), it give a positive answer.
> [image]

reference #1

```py
bucket = storage_client.bucket({bucket_name})
blob = bucket.get_blob({blob_name) 
with blob.open("r") as img:
  imgblob = Image.open(img)
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(imgblob)
```

Comment: Did you tried not just copy&paste the accepted answer, but to understand how it works first?

Comment: @Abraham Tugalov  more explaination plz, really need to have a more positive and constructive comment. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the provided links, your code must use `BytesIO` in order to work with the font file loaded from GCS.
The `load_font_from_gcs` is a custom function, written by the author of that question you referencing.
And it is not represented in the `google-cloud-storage` package.

Next, according to the official Google Cloud Storage documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage):
Files from storage can be accessed this way (this example loads the font file into the [PIL.ImageFont.truetype](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.truetype)):

```
# Import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

# Import the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import storage

# Import BytesIO module
from io import BytesIO

# Instantiate a client
storage_client = storage.Client()

# The name of the bucket
bucket_name = "my-new-bucket"

# Required blob
blob_name = "somefont.otf"

# Creates the bucket & blob instance
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

# Download the given blob
blob_content = blob.download_as_string()

# Make ImageFont out of it (or whatever you want)
font = ImageFont.truetype(BytesIO(font_file), 18)
```

So, your reference code can be changed respectively:

```
bucket = storage_client.bucket({bucket_name})
blob = bucket.get_blob({blob_name).download_as_string()
bytes = BytesIO(blob)
imgblob = Image.open(bytes)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(imgblob)
```

You can read more about PIL [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).
Also, don't forget to check the [official Google Cloud Storage documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-to).
(*There are plenty of examples using Python code.*)

Comment: thank you for the detailed explaination and also the link. it helps. both the code and finding the relevant official document